# Bootstrap3 add an icon in front of the table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, icons

I am trying to add an icon in front of the table.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-offset-8 col-xs-4">
    <span class="fa fa-pencil pull-left"></span>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th class="text-center">Date</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">01/01/2015</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need to an pencil on the left of the table on the same line as "Date"
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

One of the best tricks for positioning an element involves using the `top` and `position` properties.

To make room for the pencil, we are adding a left margin to the table. We're giving the pencil relative positioning and placing it 20 pixels from the top.

Now it appears outside and to the left of the table.

```
.fa-pencil {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a00ykzy0/1/

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I need.

Comment: I need pencil to be outside the table border. It suppose to show that you can edit the table. The table has 5 tds, which I did not include for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast. It does not work. The table is shifted to the right and goes beyond "work area". You can see that on jsfiddle too.